# Format a Drive from C#

Tags: c#

I need to format a pen drive from within a C# application.

I've googled around and the only thing I can find is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(VS.85).aspx

But I need it to work on Win XP, so that solution won't do for me.

Can anyone suggest an alternate method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to simply fork (not the linux fork :) ) a new process and run the Windows format command from inside your C# program.

Comment: Formatting needs Administrator privileges - as such you need to "fork" with "runas" or similar...

Comment: I thought of this as well. But you will need to send a "y" + "enter to the program for it to start formatting. Or can you make it silent?

Comment: @Yahia, that is correct, I'm assuming you have admin privileges.

Comment: @OskarKjellin you are right... just prepend the format with `echo y|`

Comment: I doubt the users are going to have admin priveleges, but thanks for your response. I'll try it out. :)

Comment: @TZHX You cannot expect users to format without admin priviliges